# How to set "id" in newSegmentedControl?

Tags: lua, coronasdk, null

How can I set "id" in newSegmentedControl?

I've tried the following, but `target.id` is always nil.

```
    local function onSegmentPress( event )
        local target = event.target

        print( "Segment Label is:", target.segmentLabel )
        print( "Segment Number is:", target.segmentNumber )
        print( "id:", target.id )
    end

    local segmentedControl = widget.newSegmentedControl
    {
        id = "myID",
        left = 0,
        top = b.y - 13,
        segmentWidth = 60,
        segments = s,
        defaultSegment = 1,
        onPress = onSegmentPress
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the id is for the widget, not the individual buttons in the widget, and that the event target is the actual button, which does not contain id.

Easy way to make ID available to handler is to create a closure:

```
function genOnPressHandler(segmentId)
    return function (event)
        print("One of the buttons of Segment Control id=", segmentId, "was pressed")
        return true -- indicates successful touch
    end
end

local segment = widget.newSegmentedControl{
    id = "myID",
    left = 0,
    top = 50,
    segmentWidth = 60,
    segments = {"seg 1", "seg 2", "seg 3"},
    onPress = genOnPressHandler("myID") -- returns a closure that has ID of control
}
```

Comment: @orlo I reworded, maybe it is clearer now. The solution does not give an id to each button, just makes the segment ID reachable from the onPress handler.